# Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined not sure what I'm missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and JavaScript and I'm trying to make an API call to return a list of States. My API call is working correctly, and when I console log out the array, the data is there. This issue is the mapping. When I call map, I get the error: 
 Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Code:

```
export class StatesDropDown extends Component {
     static displayName = StatesDropDown.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           // isLoaded: false,
            StateList: [],
        };
    }




    componentDidMount() {
        let initialStateList = [];
        fetch('api/States/Index')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
                console.log("Data",data);
                
                initialStateList = data.results.map((state1) => {
                    return state1                  
                });
                console.log(initialStateList);
                this.setState({
                   StateList: initialStateList
                });
            });
    }
```

After researching it sounds like when it's being called it's undefined and thus the error, but I'm confused as why it is undefined and why it's throwing this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data.results` is undefined? May you make sure that the fetch is returning what you expect?

Comment: What's the output for your console.log("Data",data);?
and what's the output for console.log("Results",data.results);

The error means that data.results is undefined.

Comment: The output for consol.log("Data",data) is the array getting returned from the server. It's state abbreviations and the full state name.

Comment: @killsburydouboy if the output of consol.log("Data",data) is the array, then you should try data.map instead of data.results.map

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so silly with such a simple solution. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
data.results.map()
```

We can understand that this data has the following structure

```
data: { 
   result: [] 
}
```

As your error said, the function *map* does not exist in ***undefined*** (in your case, it means that result has the value undefined).

You should confirm that data is an object that always has the key "result". Otherwise, you should handle these cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was such an easy solution. Your definition definitely helped.